# how to pass the name of a variable as a variable

Tags: python

How can I set the variable I want to change as a function argument? I want to define only one function, and not set_a(value), set_b(value), set_c(value), ...

```
class MyVarClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = 1
        self.b = 2
        self.c = 3

# this works, but I don't want to write n functions
def set_a(myvar_object, value):
    myvar_object.a = value

# this is what I actually want:
def set_vars(myvar_object, var_name, value):
    myvar_object.var_name = value

myvar = MyVarClass()
# I want to do the same as  myvar.a = 4
set_a(myvar, 4) # works as intended, now myvar.a is 4
set_vars(myvar, a, 4)  # error, a is not defined
```

Comment: [`setattr(obj, name, value)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#setattr).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you usually do is to create a method to the class like this:

```
class MyVarClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = 1
        self.b = 2
        self.c = 3

    def set_a(self, value):
        self.a = value
```

If, for some reason, can't do it like this and you only have the name of the attribute as string, then you can use setattr:

```
setattr(myvar_object, 'a', value)
```

But usually what you do is just this line:

```
myvar_object.a = 4
```

Comment: The setattr() looks like what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

This is done with setattr.

```
def set_vars(myvar_object, var_name, value):
    setattr(myvar_object, var_name, value)
```

This isn't necessarily the best way of doing this.  It often suggests a different data structure would be better, but in case that isn't the case here.

You'll note if you go this route, there isn't much reason to have a def rather than just call setattr directly, unless you think you'll change things in the future.

Answer (score 0):

what about using a `dict`:

```
class MyVarClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.vars = {"a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 3}

def set_vars(myvar_object, var_name, value):
    myvar_object.vars[var_name] = value
```

Comment: Guess I have to look at dicts again. I'm not so familiar with them yet and mixed it up with variables, which didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

```
**

var_name = ''
class MyVarClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = 1
        self.b = 2
        self.c = 3

# this is what I actually want:
def set_vars(myvar, var_name, value):
    myvar.var_name = value
    print (myvar.var_name)

myvar = MyVarClass()

set_vars(myvar, "b", 6)  

**
```

Comment: >>> myvar.b
    2
    >>> myvar.__dict__
    {'c': 3, 'b': 2, 'var_name': 6, 'a': 1}
    >>> myvar.var_name
    6
is not quite what I want

Comment: What you want brother